# How to get the page that was unpublished in onAfterUnpublish()

Tags: php, silverstripe

As per title, I am trying to figure out how I can obtain the URLSegment for the Page that was Unpublished.

Also need to do the same for when a Page was saved as draft

Though these extension points don't provide any variables like they do on say onAfterPublish() and onBeforePublish()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our `onAfterUnpublish` function we can access any of the page variables by calling `$this->owner`. Here is how to retrieve the page `URLSegment`:

```
class CustomSiteTree extends SiteTreeExtension {

    public function onAfterUnpublish() {
        $this->owner->URLSegment;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I was aware of `$this->owner` but for some reason I felt like a variable needed to be passed in, as for `onAfterPublish($original)` I could get URLSegment from `$original->URLSegment`

Comment: Any insight on what function I should be using to hook into "Saved as Draft", I don't see anything relevant other than onAfterWrite() but I feel that may fire alongside with onAfterPublish() and onAfterUnpublish().

Comment: I would try checking in `onAfterWrite` to see if the page getting saved is saving a draft or publishing.